# Who getting mjpeg stream from ip camera in uwp with Fluent HTTP

Tags: c#, uwp, mjpeg, flurl

First of all, i'm new an http and mjpeg-stream, so it is very possible that I only have a comprehension problem. Maybe someone can help me here anyway.

I had an problem to get the mjpeg stream from my ip camera. The link for calling the stream works fine in the browser and i can watching the livestream.
(e.g. http://192.168.xx.xx:8081/cgi-bin/hi3510/mjpegstream.cgi?-chn=11&-usr=user&-pwd=password, where xx.xx and user, password are placeholders)

If i try to connect in an uwp app to the ip camera i get no stream back. i'v trying so many solutions but no one still works for me. (These are some of the trying solutions:

- MjpegProcessor
- OZEKI Camera SDK
- IP Camera Viewer
- Onvif Camera Viewer )
  I also read so many useful articles here, but now one has the right answer.

My sourcecode looks like as follows:

```
        var newParams = new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("-chn", "11")
        };

        var baseUrl = new Url("http://192.168.xx.xx:8081");
        Debug.WriteLine(baseUrl);

        using (var fc = new FlurlClient(baseUrl).EnableCookies())
        {
            // login on page
            var loginResponse = await baseUrl
                                        .WithClient(fc)
                                        .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new
                                        {
                                            usr = "user",
                                            pwd = "password"
                                        });

            //StatusCode 200
            if (loginResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                try
                {
                    // get mjepg stream from page
                    var streamResult = await baseUrl
                                                .AppendPathSegments(new string[] { "cgi-bin", "hi3510", "mjpegstream.cgi" })
                                                .SetQueryParams(newParams)
                                                .WithClient(fc)
                                                .GetStreamAsync();

                    var memNewStream = new MemoryStream();
                    await streamResult.CopyToAsync(memNewStream);
                    memNewStream.Position = 0;
                    mediaElement.SetSource(memNewStream.AsRandomAccessStream(), "multipart/alternative");
                }
                catch (FlurlHttpException ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                }

            }
        }
```

and i got always an:
Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException: Request to http://192.168.xx.xx:8081/cgi-bin/hi3510/mjpegstream.cgi?-chn=11&-usr=user&-pwd=password failed with status code 401 (Unauthorized) on `var streamResult = await baseUrl                                               .AppendPathSegments(new string[] { "cgi-bin", "hi3510", "mjpegstream.cgi" }) .SetQueryParams(newParams).WithClient(fc).GetStreamAsync();`.

if i change the baseURL into `var baseUrl = new Url("http://192.168.xx.xx:8081/cgi-bin/hi3510/mjpegstream.cgi?-chn=11&-usr=user&-pwd=password");`  and try to connect i got the same status code 401.

many thanks in advance!

**Update:**
The link for calling the stream in the browser htp://192.168.xx.xx:8081/cgi-bin/hi3510/mjpegstream.cgi?-chn=11&-usr=user&-pwd=password.
**->** **OK**

In the Sourcecode example above the first call with 
`var loginResponse = await baseUrl.WithClient(fc).PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { usr = "user", pwd = "password" });`

**->** **OK** `Url http://192.168.xx.xx:8081`

In the Sourcode example above, the second call with
`var streamResult = await baseUrl.AppendPathSegments(new string[] { "cgi-bin", "hi3510", "mjpegstream.cgi" }).SetQueryParams(newParams).WithClient(fc).GetStreamAsync();`

**->** **Exception** `Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException: Request to http://192.168.178.35:8081/cgi-bin/hi3510/mjpegstream.cgi?-chn=11 failed with status code 401 (Unauthorized).`

```
Url http://192.168.xx.xx:8081/cgi-bin/hi3510/mjpegstream.cgi?-chn=11
```

Thats what you want?

Comment: Please can You add tests to the description of issue? You are connecting 2x towards IP cam. At first it is OK, 2nd fails. Please enter both URLs and results from Your browser with exactly same URLs. Do the browsers want anything when accessing site? On which request is there any log/login window?

Comment: on `Url http://192.168.xx.xx:8081` the browser want an login. As well on `Url http://192.168.xx.xx:8081/cgi-bin/hi3510/mjpegstream.cgi?-chn=11` 
there no login with the `&-usr=user&-pwd=password`

Comment: 1st You should get familiar with HTTP a bit. There are several options to authenticate and it depends hardly on server how it allow You to do so. One of the option is send HTTP request (ex: GET HTTP/1,1 index.php) with included Auth options in HTTP header (that is BTW the 1st successful login). However it seems Your HTTP server (IP camera) is not allowing login via URL login. You should try to find a way, how to add Authentication credentials to HTTP request of 2nd type (Stream). Is this clear?

Comment: Yes, that was what I had already thought. Ok, i will dive depper into http.

Comment: You actually do not need know HTTP better, but try find any method in Flurl, which allows You to add credentials to header AND returns same type as e.g. `AppendPathSegments`. =)

Answer (score 0):

401 (Unathorized) code speaks for itself: You have a problem with an authentication:

- The problem might be that IP cam cannot authorized You through the credentials 
  in URL.
- (or) You might have a typo elsewhere in credentials.
- (or) For remote connection not using browser, the IP cam might require using some other base of authentication. E.g. some browsers are sending this via HTTP header.
- have You went through the datasheet for comms of IP? It might require authentication for every time You are trying to connect, which might require sending the credentials during stream openning:
- I have just checked [link in comments](http://www.instar.com/faq_cgi_hd), and they specify credentials examples as:

http://IP-Address:Port/tmpfs/snap.jpg?usr=admin&pwd=instar :: Snapshot (720p / 1280x720 Pixel)

Please note that there is no '-' in front of "usr" or "pwd".

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Has it fixed the issue?

Comment: No, had problems with the return command in that comment ;-)
Thanks for your answer. Yes i know that, but i cannot go further with that error. I use the camera docu on http://www.instar.com/faq_cgi_hd for that information. 
Your sample didn't work, because `Task<HttpResponseMessage> has no methode .AppendPathSegments`. So in my example above i have split the action in two steps. But i also think i need a "second" validation or an single call with right path to cgi destination. But how i do that?

Comment: Btw, You have there 2 different user/password combination -> is it a purpose or a mistake? I believe there should be just one.

Comment: thats only here an mistake!

Comment: Yes but at mjpeg there is. `http://IP-Address:Port/cgi-bin/hi3510/mjpegstream.cgi?-chn=11&-usr=admin&-pwd=instar`.

Comment: I tried without the '-'. Same result:
`Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException: Request to http://192.168.xx.xx:8081/cgi-bin/hi3510/mjpegstream.cgi?-chn=11&usr=user&pwd=password failed with status code 401 (Unauthorized).`

Comment: Once this will run via Your browser, You can start using this within Your app. If it does not work, find another way how to log-in. I'm not familiar with Flurl API, but they should have some method like `PostUrlEncodedAsync`, where You just enter the credentials, but it won't start downloading yet.